# Can't get Crontab to work

Tags: python, linux, cron

I've been trying to get crontab to work for a while but it doesnt seem to want to work. The python script I need to initialise every midnight works perfectly from the command terminal. The location of my python script is:

> /home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/database_backup/backup.py

My contab looks like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/database_backup
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
0 0 * * * /usr/bin/python /home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/database_backup/backup.py
```

My python script looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import Popen
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today()

today = str(today)

#print today

f = open("/home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/database_backup/%s.sql" % (today), "w")
x =  Popen(["mysqldump", "-u", "root", "-p*****", "normalisation"], stdout = f)
x.wait()
f.close()
```

Any idea where im going wrong?

---

Just looked at the cron logs and i got this for each time entry I tried

```
(root) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/crontab)
```

I got the same error when i tried with a shell script aswell

Comment: silly question, but is the cron daemon running?

Comment: Just double checked, yes it is

Comment: Your crontab PATH does not include `/usr/local/bin`. But your python shebang line references `/usr/local/bin/python`. Perhaps add `/usr/local/bin` to the crontab PATH, and/or call the script explicitly:
`0 0 * * * /usr/local/bin/python /home/rv/ncbi-blast-2.2.23+/database_backup/backup.py`

Comment: `"-p*****"` should be `'-p', '*****', `

Comment: You should probably also give a full path in 
`f = open("%s.sql" % (today), "w")` so there is no question where the script is writing to.

Comment: Which user are your installing this crontab as ? root ?

Comment: yes as root, editied the code above to show where the script needs to write to.

@ SilentGhost - Code works fine as "-p******"

Comment: If it's run as root, the cwd will be / and you'll write your file there if it can. Check your local mail as well, cron should mail you the output if any, e.g. when stuff fails.

Comment: Has the script execute permissions? Did you edit the crontab via the crontab command or using an editor (don't do this)?

Comment: just editied the question to your suggestions but still no luck. I did relise the the python shebang line should reference to "/usr/bin/python" and not "/usr/local/bin/python". @ninjalj The file is executable. But still no luck

Comment: Have you checked /var/log/cron? What does it indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of using Python, make a bash script:

mysql_backup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
/PATH/TO/mysqldump -u root -p***** normalisation > /SOMEOTHER/PATH/TO/$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').sql
```

and place this in your crontab:

```
0 0 * * * /PATH/TO/mysql_backup.sh
```

Comment: You could put the script in `/usr/local/sbin` where locally installed programs for system administration typically go.

Comment: I tried with a shell script but again no luck, had a look at the cron logs and had this:

"(root) BAD FILE MODE (/etc/crontab)"

Comment: According to http://www.ehow.com/how_4397618_bad-file-mode-cron-errors.html, `BAD FILE MODE` error may occur if `/etc/crontab` does not have the right permissions. Perhaps try `sudo chmod 644 /etc/crontab` and `sudo chown root:root /etc/crontab`.

Also -- if you are using the system-wide /etc/crontab, not a personal crontab, then the format for crontab is a little different. Use
`0 0 * * * root /PATH/TO/mysql_backup.sh` instead. The 6th field (`root`) specifies the user who runs the script. See `man 5 crontab`, the section entitled `EXAMPLE SYSTEM CRON FILE`.

Answer (score 1):

If it works from your user account but not from cron it's usually not cron. The cron daemon tries to start your application but since it doesn't set up the environment variables it will fail. Create a simple shell script to setup your environment variables and starts your python script. (You don't have a PATH so you must use full path names, etc.)

Looking at your script you can do all this pretty easily using just shell script commands.
Shell scripting is vastly under-rated.

Comment: I agree, for stuff like this Python just makes it wordier. A bash script is much better suited. And this is probably the correct answer; PATH issues are the #1 culprit of cron jobs not working properly. I usually just use full paths in cron jobs to avoid hassle.

Answer (score 1):

you can just check crontab cmd, and execute those cmd manually, e.g.

```
/usr/bin/scrond run-parts /etc/cron.daily
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an idea as to where you are going wrong, but you can redirect stderr and stdout to a file in your crontab entry which might give you a hint. My syntax memory is rusty but it's something like `<yourfile>.py &> errors.txt`

Of course, this also introduces another failure point, which is that you don't have permission to write to wherever you are putting errors.txt. ;-)